# Method PUT not allowed in resquest without /<id>

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a simple ModelViewSet

```
class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Person.objects.all().order_by('id')
  serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

And with urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'persons', views.PersonViewSet)
```

I need request a PUT

> /persons

with the body

```
{
  "id":10,
  "login":"alfredo",
  "avatar_url":"https://avatars.com/2222"
}
```

To update the the avatar_url. But when a call with this url '/persons' with method PUT I get response code 405

```
{
  "detail": "Method \"PUT\" not allowed."
}
```

( I know the better way to do so is calling '/persons/10', but the requirement of the project is PUT '/persons' with the id inside the body request )

How can I implement this endpoint?

Comment: What you're trying to do looks clearly as a work for detail view (which, in turn, normally identifies what object should be updated by some ID from resource address, and not from content of payload).

There are a lot of reasons why it is done such way (for example, permissions checks — it's better when you can do it _before_ payload data validation), so, despite _there probably is a way_ to achieve what you are asking for, I'd recommend you to learn more, how to design API endpoints.

Comment: I understand that, and agree with, but as I said in the question, this design of the API is defined for others, and I cant change. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PUT method is not implemented on the ModelViewSet class, you can check this here: http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html its a nice documentation on what methods are implemented by default.

To make your PUT method work you should add this code:

```py
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

EDIT: considering that the url is: `/persons/<id>`

Comment: Won't this raise a `Person.DoesNotExist` error when the viewset calls `get_object()` for the update?  This answer seems wrong to me.

Comment: I see your point, however on the `get_object` drf calls the `get_object_or_404`: http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#get_object so if the object doesn't exist it will return a 404, preventing the error.

Comment: But it will not be possible to perform the update. [The `update` method calls `get_object`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L59-L65), and [`get_object` will raise an `AssertionError` when it checks for the id in the url.](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L88)

Comment: Ohh, I see it now! I was considering that the url was in the right format.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because the URL `/person/` is not meant to be used with a `PUT` request.  `PUT` requests correspond to the viewsets `update` method, and the `update` method requires an ID in the URL, e.g. `/person/10/`, in order to retrieve the `Person` object to update.

The way to actually solve this would be to extend the [`DefaultRouter`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L102) class to add another action for `PUT` on the list endpoint, and customize the views `get_object` method to retrieve the ID from the payload.

In the [`SimpleRouter`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L102) class you'll see the routes defined as:

```
routes = [
    # List route.
    Route(
        url=r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
        mapping={
            'get': 'list',
            'post': 'create',
            'put': 'update'  # Add this entry to the mapping dictionary
        },
        name='{basename}-list',
        detail=False,
        initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
    ),
    # Dynamically generated list routes. Generated using
    # @action(detail=False) decorator on methods of the viewset.
    DynamicRoute(
        url=r'^{prefix}/{url_path}{trailing_slash}$',
        name='{basename}-{url_name}',
        detail=False,
        initkwargs={}
    ),
    # Detail route.
    Route(
        url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
        mapping={
            'get': 'retrieve',
            'put': 'update',
            'patch': 'partial_update',
            'delete': 'destroy'
        },
        name='{basename}-detail',
        detail=True,
        initkwargs={'suffix': 'Instance'}
    ),
    # Dynamically generated detail routes. Generated using
    # @action(detail=True) decorator on methods of the viewset.
    DynamicRoute(
        url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}/{url_path}{trailing_slash}$',
        name='{basename}-{url_name}',
        detail=True,
        initkwargs={}
    ),
]
```

You'll want to add `{'put': 'update'}` to the `# List route.` section, and then customize the `update` or `get_object` methods of the viewset so that it retrieves the ID from the payload.  I'll provide an example of the customized `get_object` method to support this use case:

```
def get_object(self):
    if self.action == "update" and self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg) is None:  # Check if this is an update method to the list view, the URL kwargs for the lookup will not be populated
        person_id = self.request.data.get("id")
        return Person.objects.get(pk=person_id)
    return super().get_object()
```